"does not match the corresponding name on disk" on import in monorep with lerna on WSL2
I just started working on an existing project with a monorepo using Lerna.
I use WSL2. The files are on the windows filesystem /mnt/c..., but I only use them from WSL shells.
I cloned the repo, built it, and all worked well for days until I broke things.
Now the builds are failing.
An import statement:
import { BIRK } from '@../../shared/src/lm/bi/BIRDK.shared';
in a module in /mnt/c/users/jpr/localrepos/xyz/front-end/src/reports/bi is failing:
The error is
Cannot find file: 'BIRDK.shared.ts' does not match the corresponding name on disk:
'/mnt/c/users/jpr/localrepos/xyz/shared/src/lm/bi/JPR
As you can see, the error message says it's looking for the file in the correct path, but with '/JPR' appended to it.
JPR is a piece of the path from higher up but is capitalized here.  Guessing Windows filesystem being case-insensitive has something to do with this.
I imagine a symlink or config is messed up here, but I'm over my head and can't find it.
The weirdest part is that I have recreated the project in a different location and the same thing happened.
Recreating the project yet again on the linux drive /home/jpr... worked fine, but I was hoping to keep on a Windows path for backups, compare tools, etc.
Any solution or suggestions for troubleshooting?
Thanks.
